# ODBC, PHP while loop to assign data to array

Tags: php, mysql, odbc

I want to loop though my query and assign each data field to an array.

```
 $query ="SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE Room_ID = '145' ";

    $result = odbc_exec($connect,$query);
     while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){
      $reservation = odbc_result($result, 1);
      $reservation2 = odbc_result($result, 2);
      $reservation3 = odbc_result($result, 3);
      $reservation4 = odbc_result($result, 4);

     }
```

What I am trying to do is

```
$content = array(); 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$content[] = $info;
}
```

I guess I could check to see the total number of rows and then just do a for loop that increments the $result.

Comment: I suppose you mean odbc_fetch_array() but I can't really understand what you mean.

Comment: You are correct. I found odbc_fetch_array() literally right after I posted this. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Oh... I thought you already knew that and you had only made a typo on the post :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`odbc_fetch_array`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-fetch-array.php).

```
while ($info = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
    $content[] = $info;
}
```